# Ошибка выполнения код JavaScript в Safari

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babel, es5

Всем доброе утро. Вчера столкнулся с ошибкой выполнения JS на macbook и iphone, при тестах. Проблема еще в том что у меня самого нету уст. apple и чтоб исправить эту проблему нужно еще побегать с бубном ))

Да, есть способы установить на машину safari, но в общем я думаю что проблема именно в совместимости. Тести были на ПО apple не ранее 2017 года. Предполагаю что проблемна с использованием новых стандартов ES6+.

У себя в коде я использую модули, типа так:

```js
// breadcrumbs
import * as prdkBreadcrumbs from "./modules/breadcrumbs.js";
// products full
import * as prdkProduct from "./modules/product-full.js";

prdkProduct.changeSizeView('.changeSizesView');
```

Думаю копать в сборку Gulp. Сейчас у меня стоит так:

```js
return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.js, { sourcemaps: app.isDev })
        .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
            app.plugins.notify.onError({
                title: "JS",
                message: "Error: <%=error.message %>"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(webpack({
            mode: app.isBuild ? 'production' : 'development',
            output: {
                filename: 'app.min.js'
            }
        }))
        
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.js))
        .pipe(app.plugins.browserSync.stream())
```

Возможно кто подскажет правильно ли я иду, возможно проблема в другом. Предполагаю что в webpack есть модуль для перевода в es5 или вроде можно тут еще подключить и пропускать исходиник через babel

Comment: Что за ошибка то? Как звучит?

Comment: Не знаю точно как ее отследить. Во всех браузерах на разных платформах js работает как надо, ошибок в консоли нету. Но вот в сафари код совсем не работает, а знакомые у кого mac или iphone не могуть открыть консоль, так как в этом совсем ничего не понимают. Они просто зашли с разных устройство, сказали что не работает, сделали скрины сайта (что видно не работает) и все.

Comment: Опять же, предполагаю что нужно код в es5.